# Translating "star" (actor, musician, or similar)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

What would be a good Latin translation of a "star", a famous actor, musician or other such person?
I am looking for a good translation for modern use, but of course an attested ancient choice of words would be great if available.

There are a couple of Latin words for a star, and of course using one of them is an option.
I think that the neuter words *astrum* and *sidus* are not suitable for this use.
*Stella* sounds much better.
There is also the Greek loan *aster*.
A Greek loan adds a posh tone — in my ears at least — which I find appropriate for this use.
My own suggestion is to use *aster* for male stars and *stella* for females, to match the genders of the nouns.
But are there other options that I should be aware of?
What translation would you suggest and why?

Comment: I'm told Modern Greek uses a derivative of *aster-* but that might be calquing back from English.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Oxford offers, "celebrity" = "fama", "celebritas", both feminine nouns.

Comment: @tony Perhaps those offers are for "celebrity" in the sense of "fame" rather than "famous person", although that meaning seems to have become rarer in English. Of course it could stand for the other one by metonymy, but it'd be good to know if there is a further discussion in addition to a mere translation.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: I realise that "fama" isn't quite what you are looking for. In contemporary English, "star" & "celebrity" are used almost interchangeably. Newspapers talk of "the cult-of-celebrity" to describe adherents who hang on the every word of "stars". Lewis & Short offer exs. of uses of "fama" = "renown"--still skirting around the edges. I'm not sure that Latin has what you seek; but, I'm happy to be educated.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **dīvus, dīva** could be used, after modern Italian *diva* (which has been borrowed into English).

I think the potential for confusion with the ancient literal use meaning "god(ess)" (or as an epithet with a sense along the lines of "divine", "excellent") will be relatively small, in context, since when talking about someone from the modern era, it will rarely be necessary to express the concept of literal deification or divinity.

Comment: As far as I can imagine, the contexts for the two senses "godlike, divine" and "a star of entertainment" are exactly the same - that's why when someone suggested backforming *divus* as a masculine equivalent to *diva* for use in English, I thought it wouldn't work.

Comment: E.g. compare the metaphorical use of "god" in contexts like "[The shy boy from Dublin who became a god of rock](https://www.smh.com.au/culture/music/the-shy-boy-from-dublin-who-became-a-god-of-rock-20210831-p58nj6.html)" or "[Kylie Minogue is a goddess of pop](https://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/222214/20150721/kylie-minogue-new-music-video-pop-goddess-covers-99-red.htm)".

Comment: Of course we don't, just like we talk about metaphorical stardom without implying that people become astronomical objects. We constantly do talk about metaphorical deification, however; and I seriously doubt the educated ancients believed in literal deification either, or in any case I don't see the need to distinguish a 'literal metaphor' from a 'non-literal metaphor'. Both "divine" and "a star" are metaphors for excellence, fame and worship and thus are likely to appear in the exact same contexts with no possibility to distinguish them as far as I can see.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: I think I misunderstood what you were saying. I'll think more about it and try to add some specific usage examples to this post later to try to address it. Thank you!